# Change chevron on click event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, toggleclass

I want to change the chevron from `down` to `up` based on user's `onClick` event. I've tried using other samples by other people but it does not work out.

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dc5mLvgz/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a couple of problems with the setup of your JSFiddle, but I'm assuming that those are secondary to your actual problem.

The easiest way to do this is to use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) (I'm assuming you're okay with using jQuery since you use a `$(document).ready()` and include it in your Fiddle).

You can use the [`(className, switch)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-switch) signature like this to add or remove classes:

```
 $(element).toggleClass("myClass", false) // Removes myClass
 $(element).toggleClass("myOtherClass", true) // Adds myOtherClass
```

So, if you add `var change = true` in your `.ready()`, you can do something like this to switch between the two glyphicons on each click:

```
function toggle_caret() {
    $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up", change);
    $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down", !change);
    change = !change
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/dc5mLvgz/9/)

```js
var change = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    });
});

function toggle_caret() {
    $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up", change);
    $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down", !change);
    change = !change
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboard<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="toggle_caret()"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Requisition<small><span style="float:right" id="caret1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></small></a>
                </li>
                <ul class="nav collapse" id="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Form</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Status</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Approved</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Rejected</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;In Process</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes. According to my code earlier, the chevron are supposed to hide. Plus i'm new to JSFiddle :| Btw, Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: AstroCB, I have 2 chevron and would like to toggle both of the chevrons. When i try to toggle both when one of them were toggled, the other just wont change? This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/njw89jyh/1/

Comment: @AthirahHazira You can't use the same sentinel variable to control both chevrons; try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/njw89jyh/2/).

Comment: Okay. I thought "change" is an event that we cannot change? Sorry. I'm still new :B But Thank you! :D

Comment: @AthirahHazira No problem; `change` is just a variable that stores whether the chevron is up or down, so you can't use it for both or it will be off when the two don't match.